# How to add vertical scrollbar?

Tags: php, html, css, scrollbar

I am using a WordPress theme.

only my main menu gets too long without a scrollbar. After several trying to figuring it out still no solution. see screenshot: **http://prntscr.com/in1o7s**

I hope you guys can help me!

Thanks in advance

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. :-) [After doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Add a demo pleease ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force scroll of an element, add "overflow-y: scroll"  css directive. Example:

```css
   .scroll-menu {
     overflow-y: scroll 
    }
```

Comment: The code: <div class="hidden-xs"> i think i should set it to visible.

Comment: Hidden-xs class in Twitter Bootstrap only adds display:none for small screen sizes (<768px width).